# What's the maximum number of operators you that can be used in an if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

i'm using jquery and I'm trying to validate a form. My question is - What is the maximum number of tests can you give in a single if statement.

```
function cc_validate () {
if ($("#name").val() == "" || $("#ship_name").val() == "" || $("#address").val() == "" || $("#city").val() == "" || $("#ship_city").val() == "" || $("#state").val() == "" || $("#ship_state").val() == "" || $("#postal_code").val() == "" || isNaN($("#postal_code").val()) || $("#phone").val() == "" || $("#ship_phone").val() == "" || isNaN($("#phone").val()) || isNaN($("#ship_phone").val()) || $("#mobile_number").val() == "" || $("#ship_mobile_number").val() == "" || isNaN($("#mobile_number").val()) || isNaN($("#ship_mobile_number").val()) || $("#email").val() == "") {
return false;

}  else {

return true;
  } }
```

Comment: `$"#name"` is invalid syntax. I think you meant `$("#name")`.

Comment: just edited it to fix the syntax

Comment: I suggest jquery.validation plugin as more valuable solution.

Answer (score 6):

Why, insted of your unreadable if (and think about managing it later, also), not add some classes to your code, like this:

```
<input id="postal_code" class="required number" />
```

and have your jquery check it like this:

```
function cc_validate() {
  $(".required").each(function() {
    if (this.val() == '') return false;
  }
  $(".number").each(function() {
    if (isNaN(this.val()) return false;
  }
}
```

and such...?

Answer (score 4):

You can do as many as you want, but if you're using too many tests then you're doing something wrong and the programmer that will have to re-use your code (possibily yourself) will hate you.

Comment: ... and I'd say that the code you pasted has waaaaaay too many <strike>if statements</strike> tests

Comment: I meant tests... my bad, I'm fixing this

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use classes, just add all your field names to an array and iterate it.

Not only will increase readability, but also you don't have to worry any more with the number of operators.

It is a simpler solution, but not as nice has using classes as kender suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The number is limited only by code readability. In this case I'd say it's not (readable, that is) :).

Also, if you're asking why this code doesn't work then it as someone mentioned in a comment, `$"#name"` (and the rest) are invalid syntax. Since `$` is a function you need to put it's argument in parentheses: `$('#name')`...